# how to run vcvarsall.bat/vcvars64.bat as a subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio, python-2.7

I am trying to run the vcvarsall.bat bat script to initialize all the environment variables so that I can run follow up commands, but it does not seem to be working the way I'd like it to. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    try:
        path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat'
        subprocess.Popen([vcvars, 'x64'], shell=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Visual Studio is not installed on this system")
```

I also print the PATH variable after, but it does not seem to stick after running this function here. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a development environment when you execute `vcvarsall.bat`, but once the child process is terminated, the created environment is destroyed. In no way environment modifications done by a child process would be brought back in parent's environment - that's normal, on purpose, and a LOT of things would break instantly in most operating systems if it wasn't the case.

You should call this batch *BEFORE* running Python and your program, so all required variables will be already in environment.

Comment: Yeah, after browsing around, this seems to be the only way.

Comment: @user098213 Don't forget to accept answer and/or upvote, to help other people with the same problem.